# libGDX Mouse Input and scene2d -- Not Receiving Proper Input?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I am having trouble with buttons.

```
stage = new Stage();

Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("assets/uiskin.json"));

Table table = new Table();
table.setDebug(true);
table.setFillParent(true);
stage.addActor(table);

Button button = new Button(skin, "default");

table.add(button);
```

The code above creates a button with the proper text in center of the screen, but input is broken. When I click on the button, it does not register input. However when I click ABOVE the button, it registers input. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the code that you posted, you will need to set the input processor to the stage. By doing this, libGDX will use this as a Listener to register events that happen. Try adding this to your block of code:

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

Also, if you are not planning on adding other Actors to your Stage, I would just add the Button directly to the Stage.

Comment: hey thanks for the response! My main class extends ApplicationAdapter, and my render() method consists of clearing the screen, calling stage.act(), and then stage.draw()

Comment: Edited my previous post. Try using .setInputProcessor(stage) and tell me if that works.

Comment: I've tried that. The issue isn't that the stage isn't getting the input events, it's that the input isn't mapped correctly to the screen (if that makes any sense). Like I said in OP, clicking ABOVE the button processes a "tap" but clicking ON the button yields nothing.

Comment: I dug through the API and found an alternative solution. Try implementing InputProcessor into your class and setting the input processor of your program to an instance of that class. More information can be found on the API [here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html)